# how to recreate JavaVM.framework folder in MacOS

Tags: java, macos

How to recreate /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework folder?
I reinstalled java and it created java folder in /Library but framework folder is not getting created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JDK not just the Java Runtime Envinroment (JRE)